# weak convergence in W1,2 implies strong convergence in L2

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Also let

$W^{1,2}(\Omega)=\left\{u \in L^{2}(\Omega)|\,\, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{n}:|\alpha| \leq 1\,\, \exists \,D^{\alpha} u \in L^{p}(\Omega)\right\}$

denote the sobolev space.

Futher let $u_n\rightarrow u$ converge weakly in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. In the lecture it is sad that
this implies $u_n\rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Does anyone have an explaination?

Comment: This is [Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov,Kondrashov%20the%20Lp%20theorem.) that says that $W^{1,p}$ is compactly embedded in $L^p$. However, your statement is not completely true. It should rather be $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}$ implies $u_n\to u$ in $L^p$ up to a subsequence. I denote $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ for $(u_n)$ converges weakly to $u$ and $u_n\to u$ for $(u_n)$ converges strongly to $u$).