# Is this comment about weak convergence in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators, weak-topology

I'm reading @emily20's question in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064577/weak-convergence-in-w1-2-implies-strong-convergence-in-l2) thread

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Also let
>
> $W^{1,2}(\Omega)=\left\{u \in L^{2}(\Omega)|\,\, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{n}:|\alpha| \leq 1\,\, \exists \,D^{\alpha} u \in L^{p}(\Omega)\right\}$
>
> denote the sobolev space.
>
> Futher let $u_n\rightarrow u$ converge weakly in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. In the lecture it is sad that
> this implies $u_n\rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Does anyone have an explaination?

There is @Sub's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064577/weak-convergence-in-w1-2-implies-strong-convergence-in-l2#comment8397511_4064577) that

> This is [Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov,Kondrashov%20the%20Lp%20theorem.) that says that $W^{1, p}$ is compactly embedded in $L^p$. However, your statement is not completely true. It should rather be $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1, p}$ implies $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^p$ up to a subsequence. I denote $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ for $\left(u_n\right)$ converges weakly to $u$ and $u_n \rightarrow u$ for $\left(u_n\right)$ converges strongly to $u$.

We have an exercise in Brezis' textbook *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 6.7** Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces, and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E, F)$. Prove that $T \in \mathcal{K}(E, F)$ implies
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \text { For every weakly convergent sequence }\left(u_n\right) \text { in } E, \\
> u_n \rightarrow u, \text { then } T u_n \rightarrow T u \text { strongly in } F .
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

So I think that @emily20's conclusion "$u_n\rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$" is correct and that @Sub's comment is wrong. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: you are right, by compact embedding you get convergence of the full sequence. Subsequence only come into play at this point when going to pointwise a.e. convergence.

Comment: @daw thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: However, I think that there is another error lurking around: In order to invoke Rellich-Kondrachov, you need some regularity of $\Omega$ (e.g., a Lipschitz domain) or you have to work with $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @gerw i guess they assume the domain to be regular enough...